# Нюансы работы препроцессора и компилятора при создании классов

Tags: c++, классы, объявление, препроцессор

Приветствую, изучаю C++ по самоучителю Шилда и уже на самых первых шагах сталкиваюсь с неочевидным поведением программы. К сожалению не хватает знаний понять в чем проблема.

Итак, прежде всего, я сразу решил разобраться с классами, вынесением кода в отдельный документ и заголовочными файлами.

У меня есть такая структура:

Есть основной исполняемый файл, из которого я вызываю функцию конкретного примера из книги.

```
// Source.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#ifndef EXAMPLES_H
#define EXAMPLES_H
#include "examples.h"
#endif

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    //lesson1();
    lesson3_2();

    return 0;
 }
```

Есть заголовочный файл с примерами и задачами:

```
// examples.h
#pragma once
int lesson1();
int lesson3_2();
```

и исполняемый файл с кодом

```
// examples.cpp
#include "examples.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <stdio.h>

#include "Stack.h"

int lesson1()
{
    return 0;
}

int lesson3_2() {
    Stack s1, s2;
    int i;

    s1.init();
    s2.init();

    s1.push('a');
    s1.push('b');
    s1.push('c');

    s2.push('x');
    s2.push('y');
    s2.push('z');

    return 0;
}
```

В последнем примере используются классы, сам класс и его заголовочный файл я также сделал отдельными файлами:

```
//Stack.h    
#pragma once

class Stack {
    char stck;
    int tos;

public:
    void init();
    void push(char ch);
    char pop();
};
```

и

```
//Stack.cpp
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H
#endif

class Stack {
    static int const SIZE = 10;
    char stck[SIZE];
    int tos;

public:
    void init();
    void push(char ch);
    char pop();
};

void Stack::init() {
    cout << "Init\n";
    tos = 0;
}

void Stack::push(char ch) {
    if (tos == SIZE) {
        cout << "Стек полон";
        return;
    }
    stck[tos] = ch;
    tos++;
}

char Stack::pop() {
    if (tos == 0) {
        cout << "Стек пуст";
        return 0;
    }
    tos--;

    char ch = stck[tos];
    return ch;
}
```

И уже на этом этапе получил целый ряд проблем.

Во-первых: Не получается подключить заголовочный файл класса Stack к его .cpp реализации через #include. Он выдает ошибку redifiniton. Из-за чего в итоге я импортировал его заголовочный файл с помощью #define. Но ввиду того что я плохо понимаю как работает препроцессор, я бы предпочел подключать его с помощью #include

Во-вторых: В оригинальном примере использовалась константа SIZE которая также была объявлена с помощью #define в моем случае она не распознавалась и мне пришлось вшить ее в тело класса

В третьих: Исполнение программы в итоге ломается с Run-Time Check Failure #2. Видимо это как-то связано с массивом чаров stck и уже по завершению всего исполнения кода все грохается с этой ошибкой. Хотя сам код идентичен коду из книги и на этапе компиляции никаких ошибок нет. Я полагаю что это напрямую связано с работой компилятора и препроцессора. Хотелось бы поподробнее в этом разобраться.

Comment: Сергей, перед тем как брать в руки Шильда, попробуйте заглянуть [сюда](http://academy.cppstudio.com/), а потом [сюда](http://cppstudio.com/). Тут будет намного легче начать и понять основные нюансы. Да и справитесь вы быстрее + задачи есть. А потом возьмете уже Шильда :)

Comment: Не нужно подключать *.c/*.cpp через #include

Comment: Владимир, я и не подключал я пытаюсь подключить именно заголовочный файл .h но через #include он выдает ошибку: class type redefinition

Comment: Вы бы не читали Шилдта, это далеко не самый лучший автор.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнем с того, что у вас определены два класса с именем `Stack`: один - в заголовке `Stack.h` (определение которого не имеет смысла, так как вместо символьного массива определен скалярный объект типа char: `char stck;`)

```
#pragma once

class Stack {
    char stck;
    int tos;

public:
    void init();
    void push(char ch);
    char pop();
};
```

а другой - в модуле `Stack.cpp`

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H
#endif

class Stack {
    static int const SIZE = 10;
    char stck[SIZE];
    int tos;

public:
    void init();
    void push(char ch);
    char pop();
};
// ...
```

Причем оба файла включаются в одну единицу трансляции. В результате возникает конфликт имен: два **разных** класса имеют одно и то же имя в одной единице трансляции.

Вам следует определить класс только в заголовочном файле, а все члены данных класса, которые необходимо определить вне класса, - в программном модуле.

То есть поместите данное определение класса

```
class Stack {
    static int const SIZE = 10;
    char stck[SIZE];
    int tos;

public:
    void init();
    void push(char ch);
    char pop();
};
```

в заголовок, а данные определения его методов

```
void Stack::init() {
    cout << "Init\n";
    tos = 0;
}

void Stack::push(char ch) {
    if (tos == SIZE) {
        cout << "Стек полон";
        return;
    }
    stck[tos] = ch;
    tos++;
}

char Stack::pop() {
    if (tos == 0) {
        cout << "Стек пуст";
        return 0;
    }
    tos--;

    char ch = stck[tos];
    return ch;
}
```

в модуль с кодом, включив в самое начало модуля директиву

```
#include "Stack.h"
```

Имейте в виду, что подобные директивы, как

```
#pragma once

// ...
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H
#endif
```

имеют смысл лишь для заголовков, так как заголовки прямо или косвенно включаются в одну единицу трансляции с помощью директивы `#include`. Модули компилируются отдельно друг от друга.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все решилось. И благодаря вашему комментарию также сложилось полное понимание того что должно быть в заголовочном файле класса и в его .сpp реализации

Comment: Я бы добавил, что `include guard`ы (`#ifndef STACK_H #define STACK_H`)  надо писать не в `.cpp` файлах, а в хедерах,

Answer (score 1):

Чуть дополню, собственно по теме вопроса. Важный момент, препроцессор работает ДО ТОГО, как начинает работать компилятор. То есть, компилятор компилирует (сорри) файлы УЖЕ ОБРАБОТАННЫЕ препроцессором. Директива препроцессора `#include file` попросту пишет тот файл (`file`) в тот файл в котором встречается. То есть:

exemple.h:

```
int a = 1;
```

example.cpp:

```
#include "example.h"
int b = a;
```

Компилятор видит файл example.cpp как:

```
int a = 1;
int b = a;
```

(вместо `#include example.h` подставляется его содержимое)

Guard's (`#ifndef / #define`) работают следующим образом:

example.h:

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H
int a = 1;
#endif // закрывает первый ifndef
```

example.cpp:

```
#include "example.h"
#include "example.h"
int b = a;
```

Препроцессор вставляет на место первого #include в .cpp файле содержимое .h файла и получается:

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H // существует ли макрос EXAMPLE_H? Нет.
#define EXAMPLE_H // определяем "пустой" макрос EXAMPLE_H
#include "example.h"
int b = 1;
#endif
int a = b;
```

Потом препроцессор пытается сделать то же самое со вторым #include, но встретив #ifndef (if not defined), и увидев, что парой строк выше этот макрос определен (`#define EXAMPLE_H`), игнорирует всё вплоть до #endif. Грубо, получается следующий .cpp файл:

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H // существует ли макрос EXAMPLE_H? Нет, пока
#define EXAMPLE_H // определяем "пустой" макрос EXAMPLE_H
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H // существует ли макрос EXAMPLE_H? Уже да, см. предыдущую строку
// все до #endif игнорируется
#endif // из второго #include
int b = 1;
#endif // из первого #include
int a = b;
```